# How to apply a tween function on letters instead of numbers?

Tags: d3.js, svg, string-interpolation, tween

For a transition that I apply on a text object in `d3.js` I would like to tween the text like in **[this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7004f92cac972edef365)**. However, my problem is that this won't work if the text is made of letters instead of numbers and until now I only found examples that only used numbers.

So my question is: Is it possible to create such a tween transition on a text object with letters?

This is how I currently apply it (using the [interpolateString() function](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate#interpolateString)):

```
var mytext = svg.append("text")
    .style("fill", 'black')
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .style("font-size", "14")
    .text("My old text")

mytext
    .transition()
          .delay(1500)
          .duration(1000)
          .tween("text", function(d) { 
              var self = d3.select(this)
                var i = d3.interpolateString(self.text().replace(/,/g, ""), "My new text");
                    return function(t) {self.text(i(t))};
              });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a misconception regarding what `interpolateString` does. If you look at the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate#interpolateString), you'll see that it...

> Returns an interpolator between the two strings a and b. The string interpolator **finds numbers** embedded in a and b, where each number is of the form understood by JavaScript (emphasis mine)

So, it will not interpolate strings made with letters only.

That being said, it lead us to the question: how do you want to interpolate the letters? For instance, you can interpolate them according to their position in the Roman alphabet. If that is the case, this is a way to do it:

Create an array with the alphabet...

```
const alphabet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
```

... and, in the `tween` function, interpolate the index of each letter in the alphabet, from the old text to the new text:

```
.tween("text", function() {
    return function(t) {
      d3.select(this).text(oldText.map(function(d,i){
        return alphabet[~~(d3.interpolate(alphabet.indexOf(d), alphabet.indexOf(newText[i]))(t))]
      }).join(""))
    };
});
```

This is a very basic approach, which will work only if the two strings have exactly the same length. Also, pay attention to the fact that I put an space in the `alphabet` array, otherwise we'll get `undefined` for the spaces in the strings.

Here is a demo:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg")
const oldText = "this is my old text".split("");
const newText = "here is my new text".split("");
const alphabet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
const text = svg.append("text")
  .attr("y", 50)
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("font-size", 30)
  .text(oldText.join(""));
text.transition()
  .delay(500)
  .duration(2000)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .tween("text", function() {
    return function(t) {
      d3.select(this).text(oldText.map(function(d, i) {
        return alphabet[~~(d3.interpolate(alphabet.indexOf(d), alphabet.indexOf(newText[i]))(t))]
      }).join(""))
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: _You have a misconception regarding what interpolateString does._ | I was aware of that, just wanted to add my current solution as a code sample. 

But thanks for your reply! I think I may find a way to use this approach by not having a single text, but a `span` element for each letter and loop through the letter array to see where I have to apply a tween function and where I may add a placeholder letter (if `newText` is larger) or have a fade out transition for letters (if `newText` is shorter)

Comment: @JoeBe That works as well. The placeholder can be a solution if the new/old texts have different lengths, but I reckon you can create a more flexible solution inside the function itself.